# Connect SQL Server from Android based mobile

Tags: android, sql-server-2000

I plan to develop database application in a Android mobile ?  Is that possible to connect a SQL Server 2000 from an Android mobile, that I could add / delete / edit records from that mobile ?

Answer (score 1):

I strongly recommend you make a Web service that exposes whatever data and operations you want, then connect to that from the device.